# How to fetch values from a properties file into Jsp/tagx

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am maintaining an application where in a couple of 100 Jsps and tagx files I need to replace a few hardcoded strings - the replacement values will be driven from a properties file already being read in.

The property file in my spring mvc app is being read in like so :

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:someProps.properties, someOther.properties" />
```

There is no id attribute that can be added to  and I can't get the values through an id, so this option is out.

The only solution for this on the [internet](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/119045-how-to-get-a-property-placeholder-variable-in-a-jsp) is to declare a `PropertiesFactoryBean` and then use the spring eval to read in a jsp/tagx. Something like this :

```
<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="singleton" value="true" />
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="database.name">${database.name}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

This would soon become cumbersome if I need to read a lot of values (which looks like will be the case pretty soon in this app). Are there any other ways one could read the properties from a property file, in a jsp/tagx file ?
It would also help me understand if someone can tell me the differences between PropertiesFactoryBean and context:property-placeholder ?

Spring version 3.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: Create a custom JSP tag and manipulate accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the property values in jsp by propertyplaceholder and using spring tag in jsp: In your context xml:

```
    <!-- PropertyPlaceHolder -->
    <util:properties id="propertyConfigurer" location="WEB-INF/test/someProps.properties"/>
    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="propertyConfigurer"/>
```

In your jsp:

```
     <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
    ...
    <spring:eval expression="@propertyConfigurer.getProperty('your.property1')" />
```

Comment: The problem with this answer is that util:properties will only load the last property file it reads and discards all other properties that were read in by other spring xml files in other modules.

Comment: @happybuddha we don't have some magic to guess number of files you are loading. Per your question you mentioned only one property file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try i18n , add config information in the spring-servlet.xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
<!-- properties path -->                     
<property name="basename" value="messages" />              
<property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true" />
```

and in the jsp file, you just need add:`<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>` 
then you can get the value from .propertise file, like:

```
<spring:message code="hello" arguments="111,222" argumentSeparator=",">
```

Good luck!